# Auto preview form content before submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, label

I am planning to design a form for collecting user communication details. These are typically comprised of address, name, phone number etc.

My requirement is to create a printer label-size box below the form to automatically start displaying how the address will look on the printed label.

Any pointers to do this using bootstrap JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Mutation Observer API:**

[here](https://benfrain.com/an-introduction-to-the-javascript-mutationobserver-api/)

[and here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

It lets you **track changes in the DOM** and **invoke callback functions**. I recently made an editable HTML table using it, it's pretty intuitive. You can watch for attribute changes, DOM tree changes, etc. So I suggest building a 'template' which will accomodate your variables (address, name, etc.), style it with Bootstrap and use the Mutation Observer API to fill it whenever you see fit.

---

You could also use good old event listeners and clone the user input from the form to the template below i.e. using 'onkeypress' event. Whenever something is typed it will be displayed on the template.